# What is effect of choice of unit cell on 1st Brillouin zone?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, crystals, lattice-model

Let's say we have a 1D lattice with $a$ as lattice constant:
[image]
and hopping strength between two nearest neighbors (NN) is $t$. We can choose unit cell as one lattice site per unit cell.
[image] 
in k-space $k$ vector can be taken between $-\frac{\pi}{a}$ to $\frac{\pi}{a}$.

Now, let's consider the hopping strength between two NN is alternatively different ($t$ and $u$) as shown below:
[image]
unit cell is now two sites per unit cell. What will be the effect of this change on BZ? Will BZ change to $[-\frac{\pi}{2a},\frac{\pi}{2a})$

Comment: Yes, the BZ is smaller.

Comment: Thank you. I am confused that why increasing size of unit cell is decreasing size of BZ? Is it because they are reciprocal of each other?

Comment: Yes. What we are doing is basically a Fourier transformation from real to momentum space. We can pick cells of any size as long as they are periodic. Typically, we just pick the smallest for simplicity. In your first example, choosing a unit cell of size $a$ or $2a$ would produce the same physics.